# can't run cucumber scenarios due to test-unit version issue on Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I've been trying to follow along in the RSpec book, (I'm new to all of this) and I have what appears to be some kind of versioning issue.  If I try and run some simple scenarios, I get this error:

> can't activate test-unit (= 1.2.3, runtime) for [], already activated test-unit-2.0.7 for [] (Gem::LoadError)
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1056:in`gem'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/interop/test.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/test/unit.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.2/lib/spec/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/rspec.rb:15:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-rails-0.3.0/lib/cucumber/rails/rspec.rb:3:in`'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/code/showtime/Features/support/env.rb:11:in`'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in `require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.1/lib/polyglot.rb:64:in`require'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:124:in `load_code_file'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:85:in`load_code_file'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:77:in `block in load_code_files'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in`each'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `load_code_files'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:48:in`execute!'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
>   /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.4/bin/cucumber:8:in`'
>   script/cucumber:9:in `load'
>   script/cucumber:9:in`'

**however, uninstalling 2.0.7 yields the error:**

Missing these required gems:
  test-unit  = 2.0.7

You're running:
  ruby 1.9.1.378 at /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.6 at /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378, /Users/jeffdeville/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378@global

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.

Sorry this is probably something easy, but I just don't know ruby or rails well enough yet.